# convert pptx into PNGs

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

Is there a way of converting a `pptx` file into `png` files for each slide using Python?

I was thinking of converting pptx into pdf and then converting each pages into png but not sure if it is the optimal way.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. I see no relationship of this question to any of your tags.

Comment: I have no starting point, just an idea (pptx to pdf to png)

Comment: @JohnKorchok That’s why I ask if someone knows how to do it using pptx python library. Is it impossible ?

Comment: @JohnKorchok I already know how to do it using PowerPoint: you just need to Save As PNG and it ask you if you want to export each slides or just the current one. In python I don’t know how to save individual slides, if you find the answer please share with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible on windows using comtypes library. But same cannot be said for unix distributions because comtypes isn't supported in unix. For windows,if you couldn't figure it out:

https://gist.github.com/littmus/6496277

There is also python-pptx library but it doesn't have privilege for allowing to take Screenshot (Correct me if I am wrong.) In the meanwhile, this is really interesting question according to me, since there are many threads for the same, if you get it please post the answer over here.

Answer (score 1):

To build on natter1's answer, two things that I had to do to get save_pptx_as_png to work on Windows:

1. Install the comptypes library (i.e. pip install comtypes)
2. Format my folder_to_save_pngs and pptx_filename paths with backslashes rather than the forward slashes common in Python coding. e.g. C:\users\me\documents\foo.pptx rather than C:/users/me/documents/foo.pptx

If you don't do this, you may run into errors such as "Comptype module needed to save PNGs" or COMError "The system cannot find the path specified."

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [python-pptx-interface](https://pypi.org/project/python-pptx-interface/) - it has something similar to what Mukesh linked as built in function:

```
from pptx_tools.utils import save_pptx_as_png

# use full path for pptx_filename
save_pptx_as_png(folder_to_save_pngs, pptx_filename, overwrite_folder=True)
```

overwrite_folder=True is needed, if the folder already exists. In that case, PNGs might be overwritten.